# Test for command blocks

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been experimenting with command blocks in Minecraft Pocket Edition, and I decided to have repeating command blocks to set the time to day. 
Since then, I don't want them anymore. Is there a command I can put in a command block to test if there are any command blocks within a certain radius, or does radius only work with players?

Comment: there's no good way to test for a block within a radius of a player, but if you don't care about deleting the blocks you can `fill-replace` the are you think its in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `/testforblock` command, where `<position: x y z>` is the position of the block to be tested and `<tileName: string>` is the block ID of a block. So you would want to do

```
testforblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:repeating_command_block
```

Refer to the official wiki:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands